# Upload WatchKit app to iTunes Connect

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, watchkit

I've just created my WatchKit App for my app, and want to upload it to iTunes Connect, but when I validate my build in xCode, I am greeted with the error "unsupported architechture [armv7k]"

Now that xCode 6.2 is officially released, wouldn't it be possible to upload WatchKit apps? I am aware that it wasn't possible with the beta, but it's not in beta anymore, and I'm still not able to validate my build.

Comment: Seems that Apple hasn't allowed to upload Watchkit app now, maybe sometime later.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28129859/can-i-upload-my-application-utilizing-watchkit-to-the-app-store-now?rq=1 
According to the answer here, it should be possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't submit a WatchKit Extension yet.  This page says https://developer.apple.com/watchkit/

> Please Note: Apps built with Xcode 6.2 and iOS 8.2 SDK may be
>   submitted to the App Store. However, WatchKit extensions are not
>   accepted at this time.

Also, the iTunes Connect documentation says that you will need to have screen shots of your Watch App taken on an actual Apple Watch and not with the simulator.

Comment: But they will not be rejected either. Risky business!