# Invalid Bundle Structure for WatchKit

Tags: xcode6, app-store, watchkit

I'm trying to submit a WatchKit app to the App Store but get this error.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Apple watch app can not be submitted for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot submit WatchKit apps yet even though Xcode 6.2 and iOS 8.2 are officially out. See the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29059190/1342462) for more info.

Comment: I ended up using crashalytics beta and that worked instead. Funny apple won't support this yet.

Answer (score 6):

Another cause for this is including a WatchKit or any other TargetApplication.app inside your application bundle.

Do not include any in your `project settings > target > Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources`.

A bug in Xcode (6.2..) added it there when I tried to add it to `Target > General > Embedded Binaries`. Nothing changed in that section and no errors were shown so I ignored the bad feeling it gave me.

After hours dealing with other certificate issues (and hosing all of our TestFlight testers, due to revoking distribution certs, which was apparently/probably required), upgrading to Xcode 6.3.1 I finally remembered this bad feeling and found the app watchkit application lurking in the `Copy Bundle Resources` **section and removed it**.

In addition to the `Invalid Bundle Structure` error above the specific errors exhibited for me were:

```
ERROR ITMS-90378: "CFBundleIdentifier Collision. There is more than one bundle with the CFBundleIdentifier value 'com.company.App.watchkitapp' under the iOS application 'App.app'
ERROR ITMS-90451: "CFBundleIdentifier Collision. The Info.plist CFBundleIdentifier value 'com.company.App.watckitapp' of 'App.app/App Watchkit App.app' is in conflict with the Info.plist CFBundleIdentifier value of 'App.app/Plugins/App Watchkit Extension.appex/App WatchKit App.app'
```

All were gone and submission worked fine after removing.

Also, validation passed fine even with both instances of the watckit app.

Comment: Thanks, this answer just saved me.
I had already checked target dependencies and frameworks but it had never occurred to me that the actual App might have been added among the resources....